# Скопировать выделенный текст в буфер обмена?

Tags: javascript

Как можно скопировать выделенный текст в буфер (например, из строки поиска Google Chrome), чтобы затем сделать <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>V</kbd> в другое поле?

Comment: а зачем копировать в буфер, если можно вставить текст в другое поле напрямую?

Comment: @Grundy, как ? а если я заранее не знаю в какое поле мне нужно будет вставить?

Comment: тогда и буфер обмена не поможет, потому что ты его не контролируешь и перед тем как ты вставишь содержимое в нужный инпут оно может быть уже заменено

Comment: @Grundy,  почему? ведь если я делаю ctrl+c то, то, что скопировалось в буфер никуда не пропадает, пока я не повторю ctrl+c, или я чего то не понимаю?

Comment: Правильно, _пока я не повторю ctrl+c_, я про это и говорю, после копирования в буфер и _до_ непосредственной вставки, вполне себе возможно повторное использование _crtl+c_ причем даже на других документах. окнах и т.д. и скрипт об этом никак не узнает

Answer (score 10, accepted):

```js
var textarea = document.getElementById("textarea");
var copyButton= document.getElementById("copyButton");

copyButton.addEventListener('click', function(e) {

   // Выделяем текст в поле
   textarea.select(); 
   // Копируем текст в буфер обмена
   document.execCommand('copy');

});
```

```html
<textarea id="textarea" rows="4" cols="40">
     Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, eamsemper maiestatis no.
</textarea>
<br/>
<button id="copyButton">Click to copy</button>
```

Comment: спасибо,а можно ли каким-то образом записать в буфер обмена значение какой-либо переменной?

Comment: Вроде бы напрямую нельзя, но можно по  нужному событию создавать  `textarea` с `display: none;` или `position: absolute; left: -5000px;`, короче невидимый `textarea,` вставлять значение переменной в `textarea`, потом способом из ответа копировать значение уже из `textarea` в буфер и удалять `textarea`